# Writing code that uses tqdm but seamlessly avoids it if tqdm is not installed

Tags: python, importerror, tqdm

I want to write a python code that uses [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) for showing a progress bar, but if tqdm is not available then my code should just run without using tqdm's progress bar and without raising an ImportError exception;

For example, when tqdm is available it should **behave like this**:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def my_code(items):
    for item in tqdm(items, unit='item'):
        print(item)
```

..and when tqdm is not available it should **behave like this**:

```
def my_code(items):
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

How can I do this?

I tried just wrapping the import line:

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ImportError:
    pass
```

..but that did not prevent a NameError from appearing on the "for item in tqdm" line.
I can wrap that line with a try catch as well.. but that just make it *ugly* :(

```
def my_code(items):
    try:
        tqdm_wrapper_if_exists = tqdm(items, unit='item')
    except NameError:
        tqdm_wrapper_if_exists = items
    for item in tqdm_wrapper_if_exists:
        print(item)
```

I want something that I can do it one place near the import error, and let the rest of the code run seamlessly without having to be adapted.

I also looked at [Create a pass-through for an installed module to achieve an optional import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59720629/7325413) but the question itself assumed creating a new tqdm.py file and adding it to the system path.. which makes the *ugly* I was trying to avoid even more vivid :)
Moreover, the solutions discussed there does not allow to write the code seamlessly beyond the import statement, because you need to copy your tqdm.py file and add it to your path. I am looking for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Are you just using `tqdm` to display a progress bar, or do you use things like `tqdm.write(…)` or `tqdm.reset(…)`?

Comment: just using tqdm's decorator over an iterable object (without using any other of its methods, like write and reset)

Comment: Then your answer below should be fine, I would rename `iter` to `iterable` as the former is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter).

Comment: I would too :) updated my answer below. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution:

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ImportError:
    def tqdm(iterable, **kwargs):
        return iterable
```

this allows any code from that point to use tqdm when it is available, or to skip tqdm if it is not available.